# How to modify integer values in a Pandas DataFrame whilst avoiding SettingWithCopyWarning?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a heterogenous Pandas DataFrame - columns are a mix of data types. I only want to subtract the values in one of the integer columns for all rows by a fixed constant. That's it, and it's that simple. But I keep running into `SettingWithCopyWarning`.

Take a DataFrame of two columns. The first is of integer, and the second is of string:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[10,20,30] , "b":["x","y","z"]})
```

I want to subtract one from each cell in column "a", so the returning Dataframe would be:

```
a b
9 x
19 y
29 z
```

I've tried so many examples, and 9/10 (for want of a better word), don't even inform the Reader that their example will result in a SettingWithCopyWarning warning.

Comment: What will happen if you try `df['a'] = df['a'].sub(1)` ?

Comment: You get a SettingWithCopyWarning.

Comment: “*I will not provide any examples of my attempt, because they don't work, hence why I'm here.*” Your attempts are still helpful to help point out where you may have a misunderstanding, which is why it’s recommended to provide a [mre] of the code you’re working with in accordance with our [ask] guidance.

Comment: In the interest of my digital carbon footprint, I've removed that now, so as to avoid debate, and thus, keep the responses down to just the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = df.assign(a=df['a'].sub(1))
```